# Frame within a Frame for all plots? Why?

Tags: graphics, output

I always thought that graphics were placed in a single frame but it appears there are really 2 frames.  One inside of the other.  I discovered this accidentally when resizing what I thought was 1 frame.  See animation below.

1. What is the reasoning for having what it feels like is a redundant frame?
2. Is there a way to control the size and placement of each frame independently?
3. Would it be worthwhile to make Wolfram default to a single frame instead of two?  If so, how would I do this?
4. Do all graphics include 2 frames?

[image]

Comment: Look up `ImageMargins`

Comment: It's intended and I think it's a good thing. See documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsLayout.html), chapter "setting margins"

Comment: @andre I couldn't find an exact duplicate of this, and since the question has been upvoted I used the documentation you linked to as part of the answer, though I'm unsure whether this question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Feyre No problem. I don't think that the question if off-topic. The point is rather that it is documented. But because the documentation is not easy to find, it's a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is effectively a way to manipulate the `ImageMargins` directly with the mouse. You can see this when you run:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageMargins -> 100]
```

[image]

However, unlike in this case, the mouse created `ImageMargins` are stored in the `Out[n]` output and are kept, even if you change the plot and rerun it, i.e. `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`.
You can run `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},ImageMargins->0]` to restore plot to its original state, or `Shift+Drag` to the top left hand corner until the margins are gone.